# Running a Bash Script from (on Docker Container B) from Docker Container A

Tags: bash, docker, ssh, docker-container

I have two Docker Containers configured through a Docker Compose file.

- Docker Container A - (teamcity-agent)
- Docker Container B - (build-tool)

Both start up fine. But as part of the build process in TeamCity - I would like the Agent (Container A) to run a bash script which is on Docker Container B (Only B can run this script).

I tried to set this up using the SSH build step in Team City, but I get connection refused.

Further reading into it shows that SSH isn't enabled in containers and that I shouldn't really be trying to SSH into a container.

So how can I get Container A to run the script on Container B and see the output of the script on A?

What is the best practice for this?

Comment: i would suggest a reverse proxy (nginx is a good one ) for your connection problem between your docker-containers. and get the data with some microservices on both sides.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you've tried docker in docker solution. Check out the docker-in-docker section here: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way without modifying the application itself is through SSH. It is completely false you cannot SSH to a container. I use SSH to a database container to run database export inside it.

First be sure openssh-server is installed on B. Then you must setup a passwordless connection between A and B.

Then be sure you link your containers in the docker-compose file so you won't need to expose the SSH port.

Snippet to add in Dockerfile for container B

```bash
RUN apt-get install -q -y openssh-server
ADD id_rsa.pub /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/.ssh ; \
  chmod 700 /home/ubuntu/.ssh ; \
  chmod 600 /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Also you can run the script outside the containers using docker exec in a crontab in the host. But I think you are not looking for this extreme solution.

I can help you via comments

Regards

Comment: Do you have any setup guides for openssh? I have tried following a few but I keep getting permission denied when trying to connect.

Comment: First thing you need to do is, do the following steps manually: https://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/08/enable-password-less-ssh-logon-ubuntu-servers/. I mean docker exec in container B to configure ssh server and docker exec in container A for ssh client and key generation. Once you can connect manually then automate it in the docker file.

Comment: Thank you, this was similar to what I was trying before but I think my issue was around trying to do passwordless SSH for a root user.

Just tried it and I can run SSH now :)

Comment: Excellent. I think it is a good contribution to the community.